# Frame two picture (subfloat) and its caption

Tags: floats, subfloats, boxes, box

I am looking for a way to add a box / frame around two figures and their caption.
I am using `subfloat` for the sub-figures as it was the simple way to have two figures together under 1 caption.
Does anyone know how to add a frame around two figures and its caption?

```
\begin{figure}[!h]
\centering
\textbf{Factor 1: Industrial Solvents}\par\medskip
\subfloat{\includegraphics[width=1 \textwidth]{Images.png}}\, 
\subfloat{\includegraphics[width=1 \textwidth]{Images.png}}  \,
\caption{PCE is apportioned $\approx 60$ \% to factor 1 and a small contribution from refrigerants (HFCs), CH\textsubscript{2}Cl\textsubscript{2}, ethyne, propane, i-octane, and toluene. A high peak and higher annual variability is observed in factor contribution the beginning of the timeseries, indicating year 2015.}
\label{fig:a}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please extend your code fragment to complete small document with your figure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use package `mdframed` and put your figures+caption inside a `mdframed` environment.

```
\begin{figure}
  \begin{mdframed}
    \includegraphics{...}
    \caption{...}
  \end{mdframed}
\end{figure}
```

Answer (score 0):

With `fbox` and `minipage`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[!h]
\setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth}
\setlength\fboxsep{1ex}
\setlength\fboxrule{1pt}

\fbox{\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\centering
\textbf{Factor 1: Industrial Solvents}

\subfloat{\includegraphics{example-image-duck}}

\subfloat{\includegraphics{example-image-duck}}
    \end{minipage}}
\caption{PCE is apportioned \SI{\sim\,60}{\%} to factor 1 and a small contribution from refrigerants (HFCs), \ce{CH2Cl2}, ethyne, propane, i-octane, and toluene. A high peak and higher annual variability is observed in factor contribution the beginning of the timeseries, indicating year 2015.}
\label{fig:a}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

or

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[!h]
\setkeys{Gin}{width=0.48\linewidth}
\setlength\fboxsep{1ex}
\setlength\fboxrule{1pt}

\fbox{\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\centering
\textbf{Factor 1: Industrial Solvents}

\subfloat{\includegraphics{example-image-duck}}
\hfill
\subfloat{\includegraphics{example-image-duck}}
    \end{minipage}}
\caption{PCE is apportioned  \SI{\sim\,60}{\%} to factor 1 and a small contribution from refrigerants (HFCs), \ce{CH2Cl2}, ethyne, propane, i-octane, and toluene. A high peak and higher annual variability is observed in factor contribution the beginning of the timeseries, indicating year 2015.}
\label{fig:a}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]